# Voice VLAN Configuration on Cisco SG300

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, voip, voice

We currently have a single Cisco SG300 switch on our data network. We are introducing a hosted VoIP system. As such we will be installing a second Cisco SG300 (to account for growth and new phones) and the hosted VoIP provider will provide an Edgemarc voice gateway. As the SG300 is not capable of stacking the two switches will be interconnected with a gigabit link.

My objective is:

- Logically separate the voice and data networks
- Be able to plug a phone or computer into any port on either switch and have it communicate on the appropriate network
- Be able to plug a computer into the switch port on the back of the phones and have it communicate on the appropriate network

I am looking for guidance/resources on how to best accomplish this on the SG300.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cisco switches have a feature to configure a dedicated Voice VLAN.  This allows you to have separated vlans on the same port.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I know this much already.

Comment: it is pretty much that simple. assign a vlan as the voice vlan and add the port to that vlan.

http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/csbms/sf30x_sg30x/administration_guide/CLI_Nikola300_1_3_7.pdf

Comment: So lets say I set the Voice VLAN to VLAN 100, I expect that I should configure a single port as an Access Port in VLAN 100 to which I would connect the Edgemarc Voice Gateway. Then I would configure the remaining ports to use SmartPort with Auto Voice VLAN?

Comment: Yes. the voice vlan simply separates voice traffic from data traffic.  nothing fancy about it.